# Overwithholding due to wrong address

Tags: income-tax, new-york, form-w-2, withholding-tax

Former company in NY has the wrong address for me on file. The address is in the city and because of that it has withheld city taxes in addition to NY state taxes. I don't live there, I moved outside the city at the start of my employment. I have asked the company to send me the corrected W2 form, but they are not responding. I applied for an IRS extension hoping it would be resolved by then but doesn't look like it. What should I do? Does contacting the IRS for a corrected form make it any faster?

Comment: Where you commuting to the city for work?

Answer (score 13):

> I have asked the company to send me the corrected W2 form, but they
> are not responding.

If this is for income received in 2022:

- The company should not be issuing a corrected W-2. The purpose of the form they gave to you and the government in January 2023 is to show your income and the withholding that took place. It reflects the money that they sent to the IRS and the state/local governments.
- If the W-2 shows that there was city withholding that shouldn't have happened, the excess funds will be returned via the New York tax forms.
- If no New York state money should have been withheld, because the state money should have gone to state X; then this will be resolved when you file your returns with the appropriate states. It is possible that State X may penalize you for under withholding.
- Change your state version of the W-4 to reflect the appropriate location.

If this is for income received so far in 2023:

- Change your state version of W-4. This will stop future checks from having the wrong withholding.
- Depending on the amount of time that has gone by it may mean that the withholding from the checks earlier this year has already been sent to the New York state/local government. If that happened the excess funds will be returned next April.

Note: if you live in Jurisdiction A, and work in jurisdiction B; how they handle state and local taxes depends on the exact jurisdictions involved.

Comment: In many cases the state of NY will insist on taxing people who live and work out of state for an NY based company.  This will result in double taxation where you owe both NY and state X and can be a major unpleasant surprise if you weren't aware of it before starting a job.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight if state X is NJ, there's a credit for "tax paid to other jurisdiction" that *usually* offsets nearly all NJ tax liability. I think CT is similar. Others may be less lucky, my knowledge doesn't go that far.

Comment: There's nothing in the question about an incorrect state, the problem is just with the city.

Comment: @hobbs Given the number of commuters to NY both of those states have I'm not hugely surprised they decided to take a loss to appease their voters.   My knowledge is also limited but from comments I've seen elsewhere I think those two states are in the minority.  AIUI PA only does reciprocal deals for cross state line commuters (which we don't have with NY).  Also AFAIK NY demanding taxes for people who've always been out of state remote for NY bases companies that are doing jobs that theoretically could be done in NY is unique to them.